# Is it possible to use numeric features along with text feature for classification using scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am working on text classification. I am classifying whether a document is written by a writer whose native language is English or not(ESL/nonESL). The classification task is pretty straight forward. Until today we had feature of raw text and target was ESL or nonESL. But I got a list of words which provides some useful information like if a 90% of word of a document contains into that list then the document maybe ESL. So in python I can add another column along with raw_text and target about what percent of text contains in that list.

My question is how I will be able to co-relate this new feature with raw-text? in other word is it possible to use features from the text along with percentage of text contains into special list?

To give more insight I am useing TFIDFVect with SVM in a pipeline for feature selection and classification.

My data file looks like this

[image]

Comment: Representation of all features under the hood in scikit-learn is numeric . What problem do you see in preparing one/several more feature(s) and concatenating it with your TF-IDF features?

Comment: I am sending the raw_text to TfIdfvectorizer for converting it and creating bag of words but how I will use that additional percentage feature. When I I was sending all the feature I am getting an error                                                                 id      raw_text                                      target                     percentage                                1      is contagion ....                         ESL                         0.6                                2       this is not ....                            nonESL                     0.9

Comment: If you want something more than verbal advice post your minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I think you cannot do this inside a pipeline. You should run each step separately (i.e. Tf-idf, then hstack your new feature, then SVM). This also means you have to run your on CV loop.

Comment: Yes I also think so but pipelining is very important what I am doing. Because I am saving the classifier for future prediction and without pipelining it's not possible. Is there any other solution?